# .NET 6 not showing up in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-6.0

I have .NET 6 installed.

[image]

But it doesn't show up.

[image]

[image]

I even have the "Use previews of the .NET SDK" on.

I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Try to download and install the [SDK](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0)

Comment: SDK in "Install other frameworks"? Already did it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What type of project are you setting up?

Comment: Forms App @ewerspej

Comment: You mean Windows Forms?

Comment: Yes.. @ewerspej

Comment: And is this an existing project? The project file for .NET 6.0 projects works differently. You may need to use the upgrade assistant: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all .NET Framework 6.0 does not exist, the latest release is actually .NET Framework 4.8.1. What you mean is .NET 6 or if you prefer using the old naming then .NET core 6.

For you to use .NET 6 be sure to create a project using a template without the (.NET Framework) at the end (if coming from an existing .NET Framework project you need to **migrate** it to .NET 6)

.NET Framework and .NET (.NET Core) are completely different enviroments, .NET Framework being the oldest which is replaced by the newer .NET (.NET Core).

You can check [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4olO9UjRiww) for more information about .NET Framework vs .NET Core vs .NET vs .NET Standard vs C#.

Comment: Yes, exactly. To upgrade a Windows Forms project to .NET 6.0, it's usually necessary to use the upgrade assistant or manually change the project file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/upgrade-assistant-winforms-framework

Answer (score -1):

Exactly right like Mike said.
You should try cmd to check if dotnet is installed or not.
Try dotnet list-sdks to show all versions installed for dotnet core.
Or you can see the selected version by dotnet --version